# Closed formula for number of ones in a proper factor tree

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, factorization

**Edit [2023 Dec 7]:** One of my specific wonders, along with that of students, is around *when* a recursive formula might have – or be expected to have – an explicit or closed formula. What is the mathematical intuition or relevant theorem around the existence of such formulae, and how would that apply to this specific example?

---

The following question concerns a natural generalization of the following problem and, as relevant, a wonder around when a recursive formula can/not be written in an explicit form:

[image]

In exploring this problem, (secondary school) students and I generated enough examples of prime structures to find the following, relevant paper:

> Miller, Michael D. "A Recursively Defined Divisor Function." *The Fibonacci Quarterly, 13*([**3**](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/13-3/cover13-3.pdf)), pages 199-204. Accessible at **https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/13-3/miller.pdf**.

Define $\gamma: \mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^+$ by $\gamma(1) = 1$ and, for $N > 1$, let $\gamma(N)$ be the total number of ones in $N$'s factor family.

> **Question:** For $N$ with prime factorization $\prod_i p_i^{\alpha_i}$, what is an explicit formula for $\gamma(N)$? **If** an explicit formula cannot be written for this function, **then** what is the barrier – articulated "rigorously" or heuristically – preventing it from being written as such?

**Theorem 4** in the linked paper gives a recursive method for computing $\gamma(N)$, but, in the paper's own words:

> This theorem, although giving much information about the nature of the function $\gamma$, does not explicitly give us a formula from which we can calculate $\gamma(N)$ for various values of $N$ (page 201).

Hence the question above. Re-tagging and pointers to other references are all welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be Sloane's [A002033](https://oeis.org/A002033), namely the number of perfect partitions of $n-1$. Since the OEIS doesn't give any closed formula, there probably isn't one, but it's probably worth checking the references pointed to there.

Comment: See also A074206.

Comment: Interesting that [A074206](https://oeis.org/A074206) is a separate OEIS entry... we missed both entries by not simply listing out the totals for 1, 2, 3, etc. Thanks for the reference pointer!

Answer (score 5):

Take the formal product $g(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=\prod_{i\ge 1} (1-x_i)$ and
define
$$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots) = \frac{g(x_1,x_2,\ldots)}{2g(x_1,x_2,\ldots)-1}.$$
Then
$\gamma(\prod_i p_i^{\alpha_i})$ is the coefficient of
$\prod_i x_i^{\alpha_i}$ in the Taylor expansion of $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$.

This is elementary and I don't see how it gives an "explicit" formula except in simple cases.

Comment: Is there a way (formal theorem/criterion or informal intuition/heuristic) to determine whether a closed formula exists?

Answer (score 5):

A simple generating function, though not a closed formula, for $\gamma(N)$ is given by $\sum_{N\geq 1}\frac{\gamma(N)}{N^s} = \frac{1}{2-\zeta(s)}$, where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function. See e.g. page 7 of E. C. Titchmarsh, *The Zeta Function of Riemann*.

Comment: Very cool. This connection allowed me to find [**Ordered Factorization**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrderedFactorization.html) as a term that connects your answer with **Dave Benson**'s latter OEIS link. Is there some way to see from this, even if it's just heuristic, why there might not be a closed formula?